# Session not working in grails

Tags: java, session, grails

I am trying to store a variable in grails session of action of one controller:

```
def requestLogin = {
        def twitterClient = new TwitterFactory().getInstance()
        def returnUrl = g.createLink(controller: 'twitterLogin', action: 'processLogin', absolute:true).toString()
        log.debug "Generating request with return url of [${returnUrl}]"
        println "Generating request with return url of [${returnUrl}]"
        def requestToken = twitterService.generateRequestToken(twitterClient, returnUrl)
        session["twitter"] = twitterClient
        session["requestToken"] = requestToken
        redirect(url:requestToken.getAuthorizationURL())
    }
```

Now as it can be clearly seen, `session["requestToken"]` is storing the `requestToken`. This is clearly not null here as the redirect url is working fine.

But when it returns to callback (from twitter oAuth page) action in the same controller:

```
def processLogin = {

        log.debug "Processing Login Return from Twitter"
        if ((!session.requestToken) || (!params.oauth_verifier)) {
            redirect(action: 'twitterFailedAuthentication')
        } else {
            //accessToken has properties token and tokenSecret which can be persisted
            def accessToken = session.twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(session.requestToken, params.oauth_verifier)
            session.twitterToken=accessToken.token
            session.twitterTokenSecret=accessToken.tokenSecret
            def twitterClient=twitterService.getTwitterClient(accessToken)
            log.debug "Attempting validate..."
            def twitterUser = twitterClient.showUser(twitterClient.getScreenName())
            log.debug "Validate successful for ${twitterUser.screenName}"
            session.user = twitterUser
            redirect(action: displayDetails)
        }
    }
```

The `session.requestToken` gives null!!

Why is that happening and if so, what is the solution to store the values in session properly?

EDIT:
I am not using any authentication plugin like spring security or shiro. Here is my buildConfig.groovy dependencies:

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        //build 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j:4.0.2'
        //build 'org.facebook4j:facebook4j-core:2.1.0'
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
        runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4'

    }

plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"
    runtime ":rest:0.7"

    runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:2.3.0'
    compile ':cache:1.0.1'
    compile ":mail:1.0.7"
    compile ":heroku:1.0.1"
    compile ":cloud-support:1.0.11"
    compile ":lesscss-resources:1.3.3"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it may well be happening, because the login action invalidates and re-creates your session during login. For example, Spring-security can do it if configured to.

UPDATE:

ok, I got it.

the key phrase was this one:

> > But when it returns to callback (from twitter oAuth page) action in the same controller:

if it does so, a new session is created for the request from Twitter, so the attributes of your original session are not visible any more.

To solve the problem, you must use a shared persistence layer, so that any session or session-less context can access it.

Comment: I have no login action. I am not using spring security. Infact, I have no authentication plugin at all.

Comment: this is what you would have to do in the 1st place: describe your envirnoment!

Comment: see edit. Let me know if anything more is required to "describe your envirnoment!"

Comment: can you please elaborate on what is a "shared persistence layer"? Are there any plugins available for that? Any links? Any references?

Comment: you can a simple DB with GORM or define a singleton `ConcurrentHashMap` in a service to keep the authTokens in RAM. The 2nd approach is more preferable, as you need to keep the tokens not longer that for max 1 min. You can also use google's guava cache http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/ which provides automatical clean-up